# How to change the pictures' shape to circle?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, css, js

I had a list of users who has birthday on this month and it is being shown out by using Lightning Web Component card, however, I want to make the shape of their profile picture to be circle (like Facebook profile picture). How can I do that? Also, if possible, how can I erase all the square border of all the picture above. Thanks in advance !
}[image]

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.casedt{
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.imgBox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 30%;
}

a{
    color: black;
}
.slds-m-around_x-small{
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.slds-box{
    margin-top: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="This Month Birthday" icon-name="custom:custom11">
       <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
          <lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-around_xx-small" size="12">
             <lightning-layout>
                <lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-around_xx-small" size='12'>
                   <div>
                      <lightning-layout class='casedt'>
                         <template for:each={data} for:item="item">
                            <lightning-layout-item size="3" class="slds-m-around_x-small slds-border_top slds-border_left slds-border_bottom slds-border_right" key={item.id} >
                               <lightning-tile label='' type="media" variant="Narrow">
                                  <div class='imgBox'>
                                     <img class='slds-m-top_small' src={item.AvatarUrl__c}></img>
                                  </div>
                               </lightning-tile>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                         </template>
                      </lightning-layout>
                   </div>
                </lightning-layout-item>
             </lightning-layout>
          </lightning-layout-item>
       </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS :

```
import { LightningElement,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import getRecords from '@salesforce/apex/BirthdayNotiController.getRecords';

export default class BirthdayNotification extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    recordId;
    recordPageUrl;
    wiredActivities;
    
    @wire(getRecords)
    wiredclass({error,data}){
      // this.wiredActivities = value;
      // const { data, error } = value;
      if (data) { 
        // let lstdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log("data:" +data);
          this.data = data;
          this.error = undefined;  
      } else if (error) {  
          this.error = error; 
          this.data = undefined;  
      }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Set border-radius to 50%

Comment: Thanks for your help, by the way, how can I remove the rectangle border outside the pictures ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`lightning-avatar`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-avatar/example) to get the desired effect.

Here's an update for your code:

```
<lightning-tile label='' type="media" variant="Narrow">
  <lightning-avatar variant="circle" src={item.AvatarUrl__c}></lightning-avatar>
</lightning-tile>
```

You may need to remove additional surrounding markup or make other tweaks, but this is the intended design pattern of making avatar images that are rounded.

Another tip: You can use [lightning-carousel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-carousel/example) to create a list of images to display in a Salesforce branded way.

Comment: Millions thanks !! an additional question, how can I remove all the rectangle border outside the picture ?

Comment: @LêQuangAnh Remove `slds-border_top slds-border_left slds-border_bottom slds-border_right` from your classes.